# Android accent issue in textview

Tags: android

I have an issue with one vowel when it has accent. á, é, ó and ú show correctly, but í shows í- The log shows vowels correctly.

I've tried Html.fromhtml(text)

URLEncoder.encode(text, "utf-8");

I've tried

```
CharSequence cs=text;

for (int i=0; i<cs.length();i++){
 Character ch=cs.charAt(i);
 int comp=ch.compareTo(' ');
 Log.d("Log",ch+" "+comp);
}
```

Shows:

```
 Log í 205
 Log 141
 Log o 79
```

For the word 'río'. In textview shows: 'rí-o'

Well, I 'solved' this way:

```
  CharSequence x=text1;
  char[] characters=new char[x.length()];
  int j=0;

 for (int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
     Character ch=x.charAt(i);
     int comp=ch.compareTo(' ');
     if (comp==141){
        i++;
        ch=x.charAt(i);
  }
 characters[j]=ch;
 j++;

}
    String text2=new String (characters);
```

But it is not an answer for that weird problem.

Comment: Can you please show us some of your code? Also, this could be a font problem and not an encoding problem. Try to apply a different font.

Comment: This is the text: "El pueblo Kawiyari vive a orillas del rí­o Apaporis medio y el caño Cananarí­, en..." . It is taken from log. But, in textview it shows: "El pueblo Kawiyari vive a orillas del rí­-o Apaporis medio y el caño Cananarí-­, en" using the simplew tv.settext(texto); where texto is taken from db

Comment: I've tried changing the default font. It doesn't work :-(

Comment: if this thing happens in the LogCat too, it may be a problem with the encoding of the result you get from the DB.

Comment: I dont know why, but in logcat, when it shows the whole string, it doesnt show the problem, but if it shows each char, shows something very weird. At first, I thought that it was an encoding problem, but the database stores and let me get all the weird characters 'á, é, ó, ú, and even the ñ'